# How to merge two cells in a p:dataTable

Tags: jsf, primefaces, primefaces-datatable

I'm using PrimeFaces 8.0 and I want to merge the header of the two cells in one header (Title). Is it possible with PrimeFaces to do that?

```html
<p:dataTable>
<p:column>
<f:facet name="header">input</f:facet>
<p:outputLabl value="input" />
</p:column>

<p:column>
<f:facet name="header">output</f:facet>
<p:outputLabl value="output" />
</p:column> 
</p:dataTable>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `p:dataTable` should be used for, well, data. You should not use it for layout. Technically you could group headers, see the [`dataTable` group](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/group.xhtml) example in the showcase, but it's probably not what you want. You could use [`p:panelGrid`](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/panel/panelGrid.xhtml) for layout, but still, it renders a table, and tables shouldn't be used for layout in general.

It's better to use [PrimeFlex](https://www.primefaces.org/primeflex/) for layout. It even has a [form layout](https://www.primefaces.org/primeflex/formlayout) to create responsive layouts easily.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do it. For that purpose can be used `p:column` with attribute `colspan`. Following is example how to use it:

```
    <p:dataTable id="tliTable"
        value="#{chTransactionsForm.tliList}" var="tli"
        resizableColumns="true"
        style="width: 930px; margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px;">
    
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="#{msg.txnLineItems}" />
        </f:facet>
        
        <p:columnGroup type="header">
            <p:row>
                <p:column rowspan="2" headerText="#{msg.item}" />
                <p:column rowspan="2" headerText="#{msg.nacs}" />
                <p:column rowspan="2" headerText="#{msg.department}" />
                <p:column rowspan="2">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="#{msg.purchaseAmount}"
                            escape="false" style="white-space: pre-line;" />
                    </f:facet>
                </p:column>
                <p:column rowspan="2" headerText="#{msg.quantity}" />
                <p:column colspan="5" headerText="#{msg.promotions}" />
            </p:row>
            <p:row>
                <p:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="#{msg.promoName}"
                            escape="false" style="white-space: pre-line;" />
                    </f:facet>
                </p:column>
                <p:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="#{msg.promoCode}"
                            escape="false" style="white-space: pre-line;" />
                    </f:facet>
                </p:column>
                <p:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="#{msg.promoCat}"
                            escape="false" style="white-space: pre-line;" />
                    </f:facet>
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="#{msg.discount}" />
                <p:column headerText="#{msg.points}" />
            </p:row>
        </p:columnGroup>
        
        <p:column>
            <h:outputText id="tliProduct" value="#{tli.productName}" />
        </p:column>
        
        <p:column>
            <h:outputText id="tliNacs" value="#{tli.nacsName}" />
        </p:column>
        
        <p:column>
            <h:outputText id="tliDepartment" value="#{tli.departmentName}" />
            <p:tooltip for="tliDepartment" trackMouse="true">
                <h:outputText value="#{tli.departmentCode}:#{tli.departmentName eq tli.departmentCode ? '' : tli.departmentName}" />
            </p:tooltip>
        </p:column>
        
        <p:column>
            <h:outputText value="$" />
            <h:outputText value="#{tli.amount}">
                <f:convertNumber pattern="#,##0.00" />
            </h:outputText>
        </p:column>
        
        <p:column>
            <h:outputText value="#{tli.quantity}" />
        </p:column>
        
        <p:column colspan="5">
    ...
```

Or even more reliable source - [Column Group in PrimeFaces showcase](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/group.xhtml?jfwid=a5e0f)

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution thank you all :

```
           <p:columnGroup type="header">
            <p:row>
               
                <p:column headerText="Title 1"/>
                <p:column colspan="2" headerText="Title 2"/>
                <p:column headerText="Title 3"/>
                
            </p:row>
        </p:columnGroup>
```